# error compilation in print method

Tags: java

I get the following error in the print method

> Void methods cannot return a value

how to correct the code in method print?

```
abstract class Motor{
        int fuel;
        int getFuel(){
            return this.fuel;
        }
        abstract void run();
    }

   public class Player extends Motor {
       void run(){
           print("wroooooom");

//  public static void main(String[] args) {               
        }

    private void print(String string) {
        return string; // Void methods cannot return a value
    }
 }
```

Comment: The error says it. The return type of `print` is `void`, which means that it can't return anything (you can still use a `return;` statement to exit the method, though). Change the return type or don't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written the following code:

```
private void print(String string) {
        return string; 
    }
```

But `void` here is the `return type`. It thus means you cannot return anything. If you write `String` instead of void then it will mean that the return type will be a string which is the case and the error will go away.

It should be like this:

```
private String print(String string) {
        return string; 
    }
```

Or as it is a print function if you want to keep it `void` then print the string there itself.

> As requested in comment here is how the code should be. The main
>   function should be inside Player class. Then we define an object of
>   the Player class in the main function to call its methods.

```
abstract class Motor{
        int fuel;
        int getFuel(){
            return this.fuel;
        }
        abstract void run();
    }

   public class Player extends Motor {
       public void run(){
           print("wroooooom");//calling print method to print passed string
        }

    public void print(String string) {
        System.out.print(string);
    }

  public static void main(String []args){
    Player p1 = new Player();//creating a object of Player class to access its methods
    p1.run();//calling the run method
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , I did what you said ,, but eclipse complain : Error: The main method is not in the class Player, define the main method
   public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: @Ali12 please post your entire code so that we can debug it. Also from what the error message is saying it is highly likely that you have not created the main function. Or is this your entire code??

Comment: I did post all the code ... I do not know where to put the main function in my code ...

Comment: @Ali12 You should create a `main` function inside the particular class and invoke the methods from it.

Comment: is Motor the particular class or Player is the particular class??

Comment: @Ali12 Any class in which you can access the methods you want to use. But remember, you cannot access a private method of a class from an another class.

Comment: @Ali12 check out my answer now. I have updated it.

Comment: thank you brothers ... Brother Riddhesh your code works and it even work without print method ... thank you :)